# Making PHP output Bold

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to make my php output bold, I have tried  but I receive and error when I try that. I have tried to search this topic but none of the answers seem to be helping me in my situation.

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
{
Print "".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."<br>";
Print "Position: ".$row['Position']."<br>";
Print "Height: ".$row['Height']."<br>";  
Print "Weight: ".$row['Weight']."<br>";
Print "Birthdate: ".$row['DOB']."<br>";
Print "CNGHL Team: ".$row['CNGHLRights']."<br>";
Print "NHL Team: ".$row['Team']."<br>";
Print "Draft Year: ".$row['CNDraftYR']."<br>";
Print "Draft Position: ".$row['CNDraftPOS']."<br>"; 
Print "Drafted By: ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']."<br>";
Print "<img src=\"http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg\">";
```

Comment: Bold text in HTML is generally accomplished with a `<strong>` tag. What error do you get? Which part exactly should be in bold?

Comment: you can mix php and html so `echo "<strong>".$variable."</strong>"` or `<b></b>` ..

Comment: It's better to learn HTML before PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply add HTML strong tags into your print, removing on lines where it is not necessary.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
{
  Print "<strong>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>Position: ".$row['Position']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>Height: ".$row['Height']."</strong><br>";  
  Print "<strong>Weight: ".$row['Weight']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>Birthdate: ".$row['DOB']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>CNGHL Team: ".$row['CNGHLRights']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>NHL Team: ".$row['Team']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>Draft Year: ".$row['CNDraftYR']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<strong>Draft Position: ".$row['CNDraftPOS']."</strong><br>"; 
  Print "<strong>Drafted By: ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']."</strong><br>";
  Print "<img src=\"http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg\">";
}
```

With this

```
Print "<strong>Height: ".$row['Height']."</strong><br>";
```

The whole line will be bold. With the one below

```
Print "<strong>Height:</strong> ".$row['Height']."<br>";
```

Only the label will be bold.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to make firstname and lastname bold.

```
Print "<b>".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."</b><br>"; //<b> and </b>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
{
    echo "<strong>"; // <---- Added here
    echo "".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."<br>";
    echo "Position: ".$row['Position']."<br>";
    echo "Height: ".$row['Height']."<br>";
    echo "Weight: ".$row['Weight']."<br>";
    echo "Birthdate: ".$row['DOB']."<br>";
    echo "CNGHL Team: ".$row['CNGHLRights']."<br>";
    echo "NHL Team: ".$row['Team']."<br>";
    echo "Draft Year: ".$row['CNDraftYR']."<br>";
    echo "Draft Position: ".$row['CNDraftPOS']."<br>";
    echo "Drafted By: ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']."<br>";
    echo "</strong>"; // <-----Closing here
    echo "<img src=\"http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg\">";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think that putting such an operation in an HTML file, it is a bad practice. I recommend using the [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.

Something like this...

Controller

```
<?php
    $rows = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oPlayerInfo))
       $rows[] = $row;

    return $rows;

?>
```

View

```
<html>
    <head><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
    <?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
        <section>
            <div>
                <label>$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Position: ".$row['Position']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>"Height: ".$row['Height']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Weight: ".$row['Weight']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Birthdate: ".$row['DOB']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>CNGHL Team: ".$row['CNGHLRights']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>NHL Team: ".$row['Team']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Draft Year: ".$row['CNDraftYR']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Draft Position: ".$row['CNDraftPOS']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Drafted By: ".$row['CNDraftTEAM']</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://www.cnghl.biz/cnghldb/images/".$iPlayerID.".jpg">
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the b or strong tag to your print outputs as:

```
    Print "<strong>Height: ".$row['Height']."</strong><br>";
```

Or for the whole element as  @Shankar Damodaran has posted?