# how to bold text in php for the contact form page?

Tags: php

I have a simple PHP code where I need the name, phone num and remaining details of the user in bold. But when I use  it is displaying the same but the text wont appear in bold.

```
      <?php
       $Name = $_POST['Name'];
       $Email = $_POST['Email'];
       $phone= $_POST['phone'];
       $formcontent= 
                     "Name: $Name\n
                      Contact Number: $phone \n
                      Email: $Email";
      ?>
```

If the person name is sandy then sandy only should display in bold.
Name: *sandy*.
whether i should use bold tag or strong tag and where i should use them, I don't know what to use for this code. Any suggestion is helpful to me.

Comment: for making bold you should use `Name: <b>".$Name."</b> \n`

Comment: I used your code but it is displaying as Name: <b>Sandy</b>. Not displaying the name in bold.

Comment: `$formcontent= "Name: <b>$Name</b> \n Contact Number: <b>$phone</b> \n Email: <b>$Email</b>";`

Comment: If it doesn't chances are you have some css style overriding the bolding. Also, use strong instead of b as b is deprecated

Comment: b aren't deprecated, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1743614/5039183

Comment: i assume this data is sent via email. Unless you specify otherwise (which is unclear from your question) you are sending a plain text email. plain text is not formatted. try sending html emails instead, that gives you all the possibilities html offers for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it think it will help you

```
$formcontent= 
                     "Name: <b>$Name</b>\n
                      Contact Number: <b>$phone</b> \n
                      Email: <b>$Email</b>";
```

Comment: Its not working, it is displaying the same <b> in result also

Answer (score -1):

here we go:

```
<?php
       $Name = "Abc";
       $Email = "abc@gmail.com";
       $phone= 1234;
       Print "Name:"."<strong>".$Name."</strong><br>";
  ?>
```

It is just an example, and is working well, now you can do rest of the things by yourself,
here is the reference link for more info:
[Making PHP output Bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741876/making-php-output-bold)

i hope this would help you. keep coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Tested code

```
<?php

       $Name = 'sandy';
       $Email = 'sandy@gmail.com';
       $phone= '999999999999';
      echo  $formcontent= 
                     "Name:<strong>".$Name." </strong> <br>
                      Contact Number: <strong>".$phone."</strong> <br>
                      Email: <strong>".$Email."</strong><br>" ; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

thank for comment in my answer,
how about this ?

```
$Name='a'; $phone='wew'; $Email='sfdsdfs';
$formcontent= 
                     "Name: <b>$Name</b>\n
                      Contact Number: <b>$phone</b> \n
                      Email: <b>$Email</b>";

    echo strip_tags($formcontent,'<b>');
```

i'm waiting your respon, thanks!

Comment: I used this code---Name: <b>$Name</b> \n
Contact Number: <b>$phone</b> \n  attached with----$headers = 'MIME-Version:1.0'."\r\n";
$headers.= 'Content-type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers.= 'From: '.$Name."\r\n";-------------------------------------------It's working by doing this.